# ¿Evitar el ingreso de datos repetidos?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

estoy creando un sistema de reservaciones de citas medicas, pero no se como programar que el usuario no pueda ingresar una cita en una hora que ya esta guardada. agradeceria mucho de su ayuda

Comment: Antes de guardar la cita realiza una consulta para validar si existe una cita en dicha fecha y hora, si la consulta retorna un registro es que ya existe una cita en esa hora caso contrario realiza el registro de la cita :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes asegurar que tu campo sea unico con la setencia unique, de esta manera no habran datos repetidos en la columna de tu tabla, saludos.

Si ya tienes creada la tabla puedes usar esto:

ALTER TABLE nombreTabla 
ADD UNIQUE (nombreColumna)

y si apenas vas a crear la tabla:

CREATE TABLE nombreTabla (
    campo1 int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    campo2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    campo3 varchar(255),
    campo4 int
);

Comment: bienvenido y gracias por los aportes pero responder solo con un link se considera de baja calidad; mira [answer] dale editar a tu respuesta y añade lo relevante aqui

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con IF en tu SQL Server, algo así como:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM NOMBRE_TABLA WHERE COLUMNA_HORA_REGISTRO = @ValorHoraRegistrar)
    -- El Insert
ELSE
    -- El mensaje de que ya existe cita a esa hora
```